# What are some good WPF grid controls?

Tags: wpf

We use a grid control from Infragistics at work. Are there others? Pay or free?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd second Telerik, which is what MS used for office, IIRC.  I don't know if they have gone WPF though, but they have a good track record.  I am also a fan of [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/), and their support is great, but the wpf grid is still in beta.  The regular one is great, though.  Both of them are pay, though, but worth it.

I have never found a good free grid.  Guess they are just too hard to write.  With how... fun... wpf is, I doubt there will ever be a good free one.

Comment: Telerik has a WPF and a Silverlight grid, and it's pretty nice to work with from what I've seen of it.  Better than Infragistics, which I've used in the past - better documentation as well.

Answer (score 8):

[Free DataGrid(.NET3.5 SP1) is at CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14963)

Please see the answers in this Threads talking about DataGrid.

- [Is DataGrid a necessity in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128414/is-datagrid-a-necessity-in-wpf)
- [What WPF Datagrid controls are worth the money and/or effort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112518/what-wpf-datagrid-controls-are-worth-the-money-andor-effort)
- [What is the best *free* datagrid for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127647/what-is-the-best-free-datagrid-for-wpf)

Answer (score 4):

Xceed also have a [DataGrid for WPF](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html). It's reasonable and has a good set of features.

Comment: No, it is not free :(

Answer (score 3):

Telerik usually are a good bet : [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/controls/radgridview/overview.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I started out using the Infragistics control also which is great and is very powerful, but it's difficult to use because it's features are so extensive. I feel the same way about ComponentOne. I've switched over to the DataGrid CPT from Microsoft, and I've had a lot of success with it. Obviosly it's not as feature rich at this point as other 3rd part controls, but overall I'ts really good.

Answer (score 2):

Try the XCeed Grid (http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html). It also has a good demo page where you can see its capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

We use Xceed's 3.0 DataGrid (pro version..but free version is excellent) more extensively than probably anybody.  It has the flexibility to handle more things than the other grids.. in my opinion of course.

Try them all, there are limitations to each.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the [Xceed DataGrid for WPF](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html), check their online demo here: http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Demo.html